# Dimension of spanning set of eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $X$ be the set of all the linear combination of eigenvectors of a matrix $A$, including the 0 vector. What is $dim \, X$?

My best attempt so far is
$$\sum_{\lambda \in \{\Lambda\}} dim \, N(A - \lambda I)$$

Where $\{\Lambda\}$ is the set of eigenvalues without repetition.

The idea behind the formula is that eigenvectors for different $\lambda$'s are linearly independent, and each $\lambda$ contributes with $dim \, N(A - \lambda I)$ linearly independent eigenvectors.

The equation is of course an upper bound.

Comment: the set $X$ is not a vectorial space... What do you mean by "dimension" in this case?

Comment: @user2232305 It seems better to say $\operatorname{rank}X$ instead of $\operatorname{dim}X$. And second.
You probably mean by $NB$ the kernel of the linear transformation $B$. Right?

Comment: By X I meant all eigenvectors and their linear combinations, which is must be a vector space right?